# Why is my use of .getJSON not consistently reading local JSON files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is a simple working example that reads two local data files and appends the results to the DOM displaying a card and then an unordered list representing a hand of cards.

**app.js**

```
var main = function() {
    "use strict";

    $.getJSON("cards/aceOfSpades.json", function (data) {
        // create an element to hold the data
        var $cardParagraph = $("<p>");
        console.log("STUBB");
        // create the
        $cardParagraph.text(data.rank + " of " + data.suit);

        // append the card paragraph to main
        $("main").append($cardParagraph);
    });

    $.getJSON("cards/hand.json", function (hand) {
        var $list = $("<ul>");

        // hand is an array, so we can iterate over it
        hand.forEach(function (data) {
            // create a list item to hold the card
            // and append it to the list
            var $card = $("<li>");
            $card.text(data.rank + " of " + data.suit);
            $list.append($card);
        });
        // append the list to main
        $("main").append($list);
    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

**hand.json**

```
[
    { "suit" : "spades",    "rank" : "ace" },
    { "suit" : "hearts",    "rank" : "ten" },
    { "suit" : "spades",    "rank" : "five" },
    { "suit" : "clubs",     "rank" : "three" },
    { "suit" : "diamonds",  "rank" : "three" }
]
```

Imitating this, my code attempts to read a file with a similar array of JSON records:

**checkBoxesA.json**

```
[
    { 
       "label": "New provider",  
       "note": "check if the applicant is not currently enrolled in the Medi-Cal
                program as a provider with an active provider number. Include 
                the NPI (or Denti-Cal provider number if applicable) for the 
                business address indicated in item 4. " 
    },
    {  "label": "Change of business address",
       "note":  "check if the applicant is currently enrolled in the Medi-Cal 
               program and is requesting to relocate to a new business address
               and vacate the old location. Indicate the business address 
               applicant is moving from."
    },
    . . .
]
```

Here is the javaScript that's not working. STUBB1 is not printing to console so `$.getJSON` is ignored?

```
var main = function () { 
    "use strict";

    console.log("Hello World!");

    $.getJSON("checkBoxesA.json", function (entry) {
        var $list = $("<ul>");

        console.log("STUBB1!");
        entry.forEach(function(entry){
            var $entry =$("<li>");
            $entry.text(entry.label + " of " + entry.text);
            $list.append($entry);
        });

        $("main").append($list);
    });

    console.log("STUBB2!");
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: I have clarified the question!

Comment: The results of running this code varies between (1) logging no console errors in either example and displaying the DOM modifications from the first (successful) example in the first case. In the other case I get (2) console log errors.

Answer (score 0):

> STUBB1 is not printing to console so $.getJSON is ignored?

Not ignored.  It is likely making a bad request but you won't know until you add code to handle the error condition (or just look in the browsers' console).  `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, after all. I'd suggest just site to read up onhttp://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/, they have some examples.

Comment: In either case there are no errors logged to the console, just output from programming stubbs, and in the first case, the extended DOM is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

(1) JavaScript on Google Chrome can't read local JSON data files unless this shell command issued after Chrome completely shut down.

**open -a Google\ Chrome --args --allow-file-access-from-files**

This launches a new browser that is exempt from restricting such file access.

You do not have to do any of this for Safari or Firefox.

(2) The text in JSON files needs to be correctly formed with no nested double or single quotes!

So this in hindsight resolves my issue.